# How to print out the contents of a PBYTE?

Tags: c++, windows, printf, byte, cout

I understand `PBYTE` is `unsigned char*` from [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

I want to be able to print all the contents, either using `printf()` or `cout`:

```
PBYTE buffer;
ULONG buffersize = NULL;
serializeData(data, buffer, buffersize); 
//this function serializes "data" and stores the data in buffer and updates bufferSize)..
```

Can you help me understand how to print this in C++?

Comment: `std::cout << (void*)buffer << std::endl;` should do the trick.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That will print the *address* of the memory block that `buffer` is pointing at. It will not print the *contents* of that memory block.

Comment: @Remy Oh, from the title it sounded they want to print the pointer address. I suspect they want to print the contents in hex format or such. All a bit unclear.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "*I want to be able to **print all the contents***" - seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the *memory address* that `buffer` is pointing at, then you can do it like this:

```cpp
PBYTE buffer;
ULONG buffersize = 0;
serializeData(data, buffer, buffersize); 
//this function serializes "data" and stores the data in buffer and updates bufferSize)...

printf("%p", buffer);
or
std::cout << (void*)buffer;

...
```

But, if you want to print the *contents* of the buffer, you need to loop through the buffer and print out each `BYTE` individually, eg:

```cpp
PBYTE buffer;
ULONG buffersize = 0;
serializeData(data, buffer, buffersize); 
//this function serializes "data" and stores the data in buffer and updates bufferSize)...

for (DWORD i = 0; i < buffersize; ++i)
{
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
    or
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned int)buffer[i] << " ";
}

...
```