# vector<PBYTE> getting corrupted c++

Tags: c++, vector, printf, byte

I understand `PBYTE` is `unsigned char*` from [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

I am calling a function which updates `data` and `dataSize`.

I print the data after I call the function, but once I print the vector that stores all the data, I am not getting the same value.

Is it possible that the data is getting corrupted?

This is a function written internally, not open-source.

```cpp
SerializeEvent(__in_z PCWSTR EventName,
     __out_bcount(DataSize)  PBYTE & Data,
    __out                   ULONG & DataSize){}
```

This function takes in a field and serializes it and `data` is basically the buffer where the serialize event name is stored, and `dataSize` is the size for the same.

```
PBYTE data=NULL;
ULONG dataSize=0;

int main(){
    vector<PBYTE> dataVector;
    vector<ULONG> dataSizeVector;
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    
        serializeData(event,data,dataSize);
        printf("%02x ",data); ///----->a
        dataVector.push_back(data);
        dataSizeVector.push_back(dataSize);

    }
    //just want to print the contents of this vector to verify
    for(int i=0;i<dataVector.size();i++){
        printf("%02x ",dataVector.at(i)); ----> b
    }
    
}
```

The print from the first `for` loop is not matching the print from the second `for` loop. Am I missing something?

But doing the same for dataSizeVector is printing similar values...

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude. The serialize function requires PBYTE &data, so that;s a double pointer?

Comment: Before your next question, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And always include a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

### Both loops are printing out incorrect data.

`printf("%02x ", ...);` is being given a `BYTE*` pointer as the input value for `%x`, but `%x` expects an integer not a pointer.

As [I already showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64378985/65863) in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378866/), you can print out *individual bytes* using `%x`, and print out *pointers* using `%p` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
int main() {
    vector<PBYTE> dataVector;
    vector<ULONG> dataSizeVector;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        PBYTE data = NULL;
        ULONG dataSize = 0;
        SerializeEvent(event, data, dataSize);
        printf("%p", data);
        for(ULONG j = 0; j < dataSize; ++j) {
            printf(" %02x", data[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        dataVector.push_back(data);
        dataSizeVector.push_back(dataSize);
    }

    //just want to print the contents of this vector to verify
    for(size_t i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); ++i) {
        PBYTE data = dataVector[i];
        ULONG dataSize = dataSizeVector[i];
        printf("%p", data);
        for(ULONG j = 0; j < dataSize; ++j) {
            printf(" %02x", data[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

I suggest you read [this `printf()` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) on how `printf()` actually works.

Comment: Hi @Remy I tried what you suggested, thanks for the elaborate reply :) While the pointer values are the same(so I understand they are pointing to the same address.), the data isn't.. :(

Comment: 93 b6 53  for the first and 70 8e ce ad ..isn't that strange?

Comment: @ccoding If the data is changing it's likely due to an issue within `SerializeData`.  What does the pointer assigned to its `Data` parameter point to?  How is that pointed-to thing allocated?

Comment: @ccoding If the pointers are the same in both loops, then the data should be the same, assuming the serialize is allocating and filling memory properly. So you are likely just still printing the data wrong. [It works fine for me](https://ideone.com/EqTd32). As you can see, both loops produce the same output.